# Map native query to a pojo class

Tags: java, sql, spring

Is there a way to map native query to a pojo class?

The following does the job and returns single value however i would like to get AuditEntity object by desc limit 1 , is there a way?

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT *from audit where type='SEND_DOCS_VIA_EMAIL' and user_id=:userId 
    order 
    by timestamp desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<AuditEntity>getLatestSendEmailDateAndTime(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Comment: You're currently selecting the timestamp column from your audit table.  You need to select the columns that are relevant to the pojo that you want to populate and then return that type of object instead of a LocalDateTime.

Comment: @randal4maybe i have expressed myself incorrectly, i have fixed it now

Comment: What is the problem with your query?